# styledSelect and jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm using styledselect for my dropdowns...
http://code.google.com/p/lnet/wiki/jQueryStyledSelectOverview

I'm also using the jQuery validation plugin
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

**How can I get the validation to work on the 'styledSelect' dropdown?**

My HTML for the dropdown is

```
<select name="gender" class="required">
   <option value="" selected="selected">Select Gender</option>
   <option value="Male">Male</option>
   <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

the produced HTML after the styledSelect plugin does its thing is

```
<select name="gender" class="required" style="display: none;">
       <option value="" selected="selected">Select Gender</option>
       <option value="Male">Male</option>
       <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>    

<div class="styledSelect">
       <ul>
          <li rel class="option selected first">Select Gender</li>
          <li rel="Male" class="option">Male</li>
          <li rel="Female" class="option last">Female</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

the selected element (li) from from list gets the class of 'selected'.

My current js for the validate plugin is in its simplest setup.

```
$('.signupform').validate();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/456/) jsfiddle I made should explain it. You can use the `errorPlacement` option to position the error message wherever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*validate form*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#form1").validate({
        rules:{
            gender: {required: true}

        },
    errorClass: "invalid",
        errorElement: "div"
    });
}); 
</script>
```